# Gym time after lunch

Tags: workout, gym

Normally, when I wake up I don't have any hunger. I eat directly at 12:30 sharp due to work hours so I can go to the gym in afternoon? My question is: **how much time should I wait for before I work-out?**

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what this question is about.

Comment: What do you do at the gym? What are your goals?

Comment: @Informaficker the crux of the question is how long after eating should you wait before working out.

Comment: @Moses After the edit it's more clear. Pretty sure we already had a question exactly like this, but cannot find it.

Comment: depending on how heavy the meal is, I'd suggest 15-30 minutes, if it's a protein bar or shake you can work out right afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just give it enough time such that you don't puke during your workout. Some people I know can go 25 minutes after their meal but others maybe hours. Of course you don't want to go IMMEDIATELY after a meal. This also depends on what type of workout you are doing (you might want to give it an hour or so if you are going to do stuff like crazy jumping).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the answer here is somewhat subjective in that the bodies of different people handle exercising on a non-empty stomach differently. The [general rule I've found](https://www.livestrong.com/article/292099-how-long-after-you-eat-can-you-workout/) is that you don't need to wait after a light snack, you should wait an hour or two after a light meal, and you should wait three to four hours after a heavier one.

If you eat a typical lunch, you're probably looking at being able to work out within an hour, enough time to digest a decent amount of the food so as to avoid stomach cramps and nausea.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, you are following an extremely unhealthy approach. You need to have breakfast or eat within an hour of waking up. This will kick-start your metabolism for the  day. Google skipping breakfast to understand what I mean.

As far as your question is concerned, it really depends on what and how much you eat for lunch. Ideally you can hit the gym floor about 45-60 mins after meal.

-- Update --
[Breakfast most important meal](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2824987.stm)

Comment: There is actually nothing saying that eating breakfast is healthier then eating breakfast. It has actually been pretty much proven that you can eat however you like without change in metabolism during the day. So to "kick-start" your metabolism is pretty much BS. 

There are quite alot of different cultures where breakfast is non existing, and they seem to be as healthy as anyone else.

Comment: @conMan: I understand that there are certainly a lot of myths that oft repeated become the norm but skipping breakfast is not one of them. I would not like to get into the details of science behind it but you can definitely look around and please show some source to support your claim.

Comment: -1 Instead of telling someone to google something, please provide reference and cite from crucial parts.

Comment: Thanks guys  to be more clear ,I wake at around 10 am morning